# Strange SESSION output with switch

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, switch-statement, session-variables

Hi I am working on a page where a customer can select some items. When a customer clicks on one of the select buttons the `?glasstype` gets set and will be saved into the `$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number']`

Then I check with a switch if `$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number']` is `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` or `5` and then I set the `$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['name']` to a name of the product.

But now I got 2 problems:

1. When I `print_r` the `$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number']` the page shows me only the first letter of the `$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['name']`, so **B**(lank) or **S**(atijnglas) etc etc.
2. Now I cannot check `$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number']` anymore to add a class to the selected button.

I think I am doing something wrong in the switch but don't know what. Can someone give me some advice?

```
session_start();    

if(isset($_GET['glasstype'])) :
        $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number'] = $_GET['glasstype'];
    endif;

    switch($_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number']) {

        case '1' :
            $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['name'] = "Blank";
            break;
        case '2' :
            $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['name'] = 'Satijnglas';
            break;
        case '3' :
            $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['name'] = 'Brons';
            break;
        case '4' :
            $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['name'] = 'Grijs';
            break;
        case '5' :
            $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['name'] = 'Crepi';
            break;  

    }

    print_r($_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number']);
```

HTML (set the `?glasstype`):

```
<a class="choice_button<?php if($_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number'] == 1) echo ' selected'; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?glasstype=1">Select</a>

<a class="choice_button<?php if($_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number'] == 2) echo ' selected'; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?glasstype=2">Select</a>

<a class="choice_button<?php if($_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number'] == 3) echo ' selected'; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?glasstype=3">Select</a>
```

Comment: Why would `print_r` of the number show any part of the name? It should just show `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.

Comment: Can you provide content of `var_dump($_SESSION);` when you get only first letter of option ?

Comment: @Barmar yeah that's what I was expecting.

Comment: I don't see any way the code you posted could be putting letters into `$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number']`

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET['glasstype'])` show?

Comment: @barmar it shows: string(1) "1", no me neither

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's something in your real code that didn't get copied here. Check it really carefully for typos.

Comment: Okay I will check it again. But when I remove my switch and do print_r($_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']['number']); it shows: 1 and if place the switch back it gives me "B" from "Blank"

Comment: I searched my code and can't find any wrong code. I changed the switch to an if statement but gives the same problem..